What determines the concentration of acid at fixed concentrations of hydroxyl ion and conjugate base?
This is a question from OpenStax:

Determine the acetic acid concentration in a solution with  $[\ce{CH3CO2−}]= \pu{0.050 M}$  and $[\ce{OH−}] = \pu{2.5E-6 M}$ at equilibrium.

I get the calculation but have trouble understanding the fact that the concentration of acetic acid and the concentration of hydroxide ion are different. I would have thought that the concentration of acetic acid is also $\pu{2.5E-6 M}$, given one mole of acetate ion hydrolyzed to yield one mole of acetic acid and one mole of hydroxide ion. Appreciate greatly any help.

I think in the example they are not describing the hydrolysis of sodium acetate. Take into account the the solution described has an acid pH (pH = 5.6).

There are sentences above the question stating that the reaction is base hydrolysis. The sentences are worded as follows: "The acetate ion,  CH3CO2−, is the conjugate base of acetic acid, CH3CO2H, and so its base ionization (or base hydrolysis) reaction is represented by
CH3CO2−(aq)+H2O(l)⇌CH3CO2H(aq)+OH−(aq). I thought the pH is greater than 7, given that hydroxide ion is not acidic. Thanks PAEP.

@PAEP The hydroxide concentration is higher than in neutral solution, so it is basic rather than acidic.


[OP] I would have thought that the concentration of acetic acid is also $\pu{2.5E−6 M}$, given one mole of acetate ion hydrolyzed to yield one mole of acetic acid and one mole of hydroxide ion.

You are assuming that you start out with pure sodium acetate (or another cation as counterion). This would result in a basic solution with pH about 8.7. However, the pH is about 8.4, so there is some extra acid in there.
Once we have the concentration of acetic acid, we can also look at the charge balance. Looking at the published solution, we have the following:
Sum of concentration of negatively charged ions:
$$c_\mathrm{neg} = \pu{0.05 M} + \pu{2.5E−6 M} = \pu{5.00025E-2 M} $$
Sum of concentrations of positively charged ions:
$$c_\mathrm{pos} = \pu{1.1E-5 M} + \pu{4E−9 M} = \pu{1.1004E-5 M}$$
To get to a neutral solution, it has to contain more cations:
$$c_\mathrm{extra\ cation} = \pu{5.00025E-2 M} - \pu{0.0011004E-2 M} < \pu{0.05 M}$$
This does not work by using just sodium acetate (the sum of acetate and acetic acid concentration at equilibrium is larger than the concentration of extra cation needed).
Instead, you can either start with a mixture of sodium acetate and acetic acid, or start with sodium acetate and add some HCl, or start with acetic acid and add a lot of NaOH to get this pH with the given acetate concentration.
For a mixture of acetic acid and sodium acetate, $\pu{8.5E-6 M}$ would have to be acetic acid, and the rest (a bit more than 0.05 M, about 0.0500025) would be sodium acetate. As the solution approaches equilibrium, some of the acetate turns into acetic acid, making hydroxide from water.
None of these considerations are necessary to solve the problem given in the textbook. It is interesting, however, to figure out how you could get to this situation.
One should add that theoretically, we should not pretend these numbers are accurate because of non-ideality of solutions. In practice, you would just set the pH by adding strong acid or base (you can't control solution concentrations with that many significant figures, and starting materials are never 100% pure), and the pH would fluctuate because of secondary effects (change in temperature, exposure to carbon dioxide, etc), so this is more a thought experiment.

Sum of concentration of positive ions I have is 0.05M from Na+ plus 1.11x10-5M from hydronium ions reacting with acetate ions. Am I incorrect? Thanks

No, you can't assume 0.05 M from Na+, that is not specified. It has to match the negative ions though, whose equilibrium concentrations are given. Because Na+ is a spectator ion, that concentration does not change.
